# SQL Join with an OR Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say we have the following query

```
select
     *
from
     table_1 as a
left join
     table_2 as b
     on
          a.[id_1] = b.[emp_id] OR
          a.[id_1] = b.[worker_id]
```

How is that query different from the below:

```
    select
         *
    from
         table_1 as a
    left join
         table_2 as b
         on
              a.[id_1] = b.[emp_id] 

union

    select
         *
    from
         table_1 as a
    left join
         table_2 as b
         on
              a.[id_1] = b.[worker_id]
```

Aren't both queries synonymous as far as the results go? The query with the union performs much faster, but I'm getting a different record count, that's why I'm asking.

**Edit # 1**

There are no indexes and I am not allowed to add any.

The top query takes 20 minutes to run.
The bottom query takes 2 minutes to run.

This is why I am trying to manipulate the bottom query in a way that replicates the top query.

39,758 records are returned in the top query.
Approximately 78,000 records are returned in the second.

Using an `OR` instead of an `IN` because that's how someone designed the stored procedure. I'm simply taking it apart to try and adjust something else in the stored procedure.

**Edit #2:**

I am creating #temp tables and throwing indexes on those as a solution. Before throwing indexes on, I need to make sure I replicate the same number of records.

**Edit #3: **

If you want to reproduce what I am doing, here is an example:

```
drop table #temp;
go

drop table #temp_2;
go
-----------------------------------

select
    1 as [id],
    cast('good' as varchar(255)) as [status]
into
    #temp;

go

insert into #temp(id,[status]) values
(2, 'bad'), (3, 'great'), (4, 'average');

go
------------------------------------------

select
    1 as [id],
    cast('good' as varchar(255)) as [status]
into
    #temp_2;
go

insert into #temp_2(id, [status]) values
(2, 'average'), (5, 'average'), (6, 'average');

go
-------------------------------------------------
select
    a.*,
    b.*
from
    #temp as a
left join
    #temp_2 as b
    on
        a.[id] = b.[id];

go

select
    a.*,
    b.*
from
    #temp as a
left join
    #temp_2 as b
    on
        a.[status] = b.[status];

go

select
    a.*,
    b.*
from
    #temp as a
left join
    #temp_2 as b
    on
        a.[id] = b.[id] OR
        a.[status] = b.[status];

go
```

If you look at the very last query, the record in both tables where the ID = 1, you will notice that there is a match on both the ID value and the status; however, only 1 record is returned.

Comment: Certainly these 2 are not the same "underneath". I am also suprised you say the `UNION` is faster, as `DISTINCT` has a large overhead for a query, as would the need to 2 likely scans. Unless you don't have an index that includes both `emp_id` and `worker_id`.

Comment: Side note: Why `OR` and not an `IN`?

Comment: Edited my original post to answer questions. See Edit #1

Comment: it would be interesting to see a query plan

Comment: Since there are no indexes on this table and you are not allowed to add any then there is NOTHING you can do to help the performance. That is like taking your car to the gas station because it is out of gas but you aren't allowed to put any gas in the tank. Honestly 2 minutes to return 78,000 rows is way beyond the acceptable amount of time to begin with.

Comment: Could you have some records where a.[id_1] = b.[emp_id] AND a.[id_1] = b.[worker_id] resulting in one row in the top query, but two rows in the bottom query?

Comment: I am creating #temp tables and throwing indexes on those :)

Comment: The one with UNION return more records than the one with the `OR`?! It that really so? It doesn't make sens, since UNION add a distinct on top and should have less instead of more.

Comment: I think the key to understanding this is to understand how the OR keyword works.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Sure, give me 10 minutes.

Comment: @SeanLange Please see my edit #3

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plans in your question. Your example compares different columns. `id` to `id` or `status` to `status`, while the original query compared `id_1` to `emp_id` and `worker_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is wrong, please see **Edit #3**, in my question, to replicate my results.

Old way of thinking:

> If I join using an OR clause, there will be a check to see if
>   something matches on the first criteria and then it will try to match
>   on the second criteria.

New way of thinking:

> If I join using an OR clause, there will be a check to see if
>   something matches on the first criteria. If there is no match, it will
>   then try on the second criteria.

Answer (score 5):

Answering you question: "Aren't both queries synonymous as far as the results go?"
No.
Both your joins are left joins, so you need to think about 3 scenarions:
1. rows in both right tables exists -> will produce same records
2. rows in only one right table exists -> union will produce two or more rows with one row of NULL values for right table and matching rows from other right table. Pure JOIN will not produce row with NULLs.
3. rows in both right tables don't exists -> same results (2 rows combined by distinct)

Comment: Bingo, I have scenario 2.

I am trying to join, instead of union, my results in the bottom have of the query in a way that produces the same number of records as the top query. My top query has 39,758 records and my attempt to join the bottom 2 queries together instead of unioning them has left me with 39,641 records, so I'm trying to figure out where I can go from there.

Comment: @lunchBox This is different from your question, just use `UNION ALL` to have the same number of rows.

Comment: Union ALL will not work @AXMIM, I am currently working on a way to allow others to reproduce the results.

Comment: Ok, yes I see now